# Strange Chrome image behaviour:

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

The following website was originally developed in Chrome. So I am sure it used to appear as expected. I don't know exactly when, maybe after a chrome update, the header image seems to be cut for no reason i can understand.

Live Website: [www.lepiadive.com](http://www.lepiadive.com)

Firefox screenshot (correct):
[image: firefox]

Chrome screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Try and add this to the css `* { border:1px solid red; }` and you might find what's causing the spacing.

Comment: why don't you add the image as background to your div with class `header-v2` or `container`. It's more reasonable and it works, I tried it

Comment: Indeed @Chris I ve thought of background img but I cannot make it scale nicely for responsive design

Comment: @AntonisGr did you try with `background-size` in percentages

Comment: @Chris I will prefer the more simple Gust's answer. Thank you for your time. If you make it an answer I will upvote it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `.header-v2`'s position to `absolute` and add `width: 100%;`.

Although you told `.header-v2` to stay `0px` high, its content **did** take up space. This is due to the fact that `.header-v2` had position `relative`. An element with position `absolute` will never take up any space, though. So all that's left to do is telling the element to take full width of the page, and you're done!

Comment: Seems perfect! Could you explain me the reasons for this behaviour? (I will test it for a couple of minutes before accepting)

Comment: Thank you for your time. What is really strange is that before some months it was fine in Chrome, and also it still is in Firefox! (although it seems to exist a CSS problem)

Comment: It's not your CSS, it's probably just a bug in Chrome. I guess it will be fixed sooner or later